# How to get input value into ajax request

Tags: javascript, html, api

I'm don't know how to get the value from the textbox into my search query, for the API I'm using.
In this example I want to get information about London, but how can I replace `London` with the value from the `city` text-input.

```
$.getJSON('https://api.search?near=LONDON&v=20120101',
<body onLoad="init()">
Search the place: <input type="text" id="city" class="cjtxt"></input>
```

I tried to do the following:

```
$.getJSON('https://api.search?near=+city&v=20120101', function(){});
```

But with no success.. What am I doing wrong, and how can I solve this?

Any idea?

Comment: If you need additonal help, please provide a JSFiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Most simple version**

You add an event listener to the input field, and every time it changes, you then collect the value, and put it into the Ajax Request.

```
$("#city").change(function(){
    var city = $(this).val();
    $.getJSON('https://api.search?near=' + city  + '&v=20120101', 
        function(data){
        // Your data will be available here
    });
});
```

**Added functionality**

You should guard the request with some sort of validation logic, fx. it can't be less the 2 characters long, or only be requested when the user has stopped typing for 500 milliseconds.

**Exmaple #1 - Minimum 2 characters:**

```
$("#city").change(function(){
    var city = $(this).val();
    if(city && city.length >= 2){
        $.getJSON('https://api.search?near=' + city  + '&v=20120101', 
           function(data){
            // Your data will be available here
        });
    }
});
```

**Exmaple #2 - Request after user stopped typing(500ms):**

```
var cityTimeoutId;
$("#city").change(function(){
    // Stop the 'Timeout' if it haven't already been fired
    clearTimeout(cityTimeoutId); 
    var city = $(this).val();
    // Set the timeout, meaning it will run this method in 500ms
    cityTimeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
        $.getJSON('https://api.search?near=' + city  + '&v=20120101', 
            function(data){
            // Your data will be available here
        });
    }, 500);//<- The 500ms is set here, as the last param of the timeout function
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I have a problem to make it works. This is my case: http://jsfiddle.net/3HSjY/7/

Comment: @anna Sure thing, but you need to boil it down to the problem, that is waaay to much code for me to debug. Boil it down to the essential problem, and then I can help you.

Comment: André, this is the description of the problem that i have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21395599/openlayers-geonames-and-api-jsonp

Comment: i can't make it work in this example. This is how it was before: http://jsfiddle.net/3HSjY/10/ (line 30) and it doesn't work once i change it as advised: http://jsfiddle.net/3HSjY/11/ (line 29-31)

Comment: Your code is simply too big and messy for me to use time on digging through it. Start by removing parts until you atleast don't get errors. And then build upon it again to make it work.

Comment: Thank you for your help! You are great! But when i check this: http://jsfiddle.net/3HSjY/14/ I can see on the map the place that i writted on the search box but can not see the markers on the map :/

Comment: @anna This is as far as I will take this: http://jsfiddle.net/3HSjY/16/ Now it also shows markers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an inline event handler:

```
Search the place: 
<input type="text" id="city" class="cjtxt" onchange="myfunction(this);"></input>

function myfunction(input){
    $.getJSON('https://api.search?near='+input.value+'&v=20120101');
}
```